# How to subsample unbalanced classes in regression problems using R-caret?

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, r-caret

I'm very new to stack overflow and predictive modeling. I'm trying to predict leaf size based on spectroscopy. However, leaf size (a continuous variable) is dependent on plant life form (in my case, 3 categorical classes). This classes are heavily unbalanced. The bottom line is, I would like to know how well spectroscopy predict leaf size within each class. At the moment, I am not sure how to split my dataset, most examples I've found online are for strictly classification problems and I'm not really sure if it applies to this case. Do I have to build a separate training set for each class, or that is a proper way of subsampling (down, up, etc) the training set and then performing the regression? I am using the caret package on R, since I am also building an ensemble of machine learning methods and caret seemed to be the most user-friendly way to do it.
My dataset consist of 1647 predictors and 1500 observations. So far, I am building separate models for each class, but it doesn't seem to be the correct way of doing it.

```
library(caret)
library(dplyr)
#data
 str(df,10)
'data.frame':   1648 obs. of  1904 variables:
$ life_form: Factor w/ 3 levels "","herbaceous",..
$ leaf_size: num  120.4 73.6 85.4 60.1 108.7 ...
$ X601     : num  0.0847 0.1065 0.1286 0.084 0.0967 ...
$ X602     : num  0.0844 0.1062 0.1284 0.0837 0.0964 ...
$ X603     : num  0.0841 0.1058 0.1281 0.0833 0.0961 ...
$ X604     : num  0.0837 0.1053 0.1277 0.0829 0.0957 ...
$ X605     : num  0.0833 0.1049 0.1273 0.0824 0.0953 ...
$ X606     : num  0.0828 0.1044 0.1269 0.0819 0.0948 ...
$ X607     : num  0.0823 0.1039 0.1265 0.0814 0.0943 ...
$ X608     : num  0.0818 0.1033 0.1259 0.0809 0.0937 ...
 ....
$ X2500    : num  0.0853 0.1072 0.129 0.0847 0.0972 ...

  df %>% 
  group_by(life_form) %>% 
  summarise(n = n())

# A tibble: 
1 ""             4
2 grass        564
3 herbaceous   227
4 woody        853

#Filtering per class
woody = df %>% dplyr::filter(life_form =="woody")

# Data partition
index <- createDataPartition(woody$leaf_size, p = 0.7, list = FALSE)
train_data <- woody[index, ]
test_data  <- woody[-index, ]

control = trainControl(method ="cv",number= 10, repeat=5,   selectionFunction = "oneSE")
set.seed(1234)
mod1 <- train(tam_folha ~ ., data = train_data,
method = "pls",
metric = "RMSE",
tuneLength = 10,
trControl = control)

### Repeat to other life form classes
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a specific programming question. If you have questions about data modeling, you should probably ask over at [stats.se] or [datascience.se]. That fact that you want to use R here doesn't seem particularly relevant to your underlying question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem a little confused; clearly, you do **not** have a class imbalance issue.

Class imbalance is applicable in classification settings only (you are in a regression one); it has to do with the classes (outcomes, i.e. what you are trying to predict), and not with the *features* as in your case. A textbook example is when you have a binary classification problem (0/1), where, say, 99% of your samples are of class 0, and you need to employ specific techniques in order to prevent your classifier from getting a 99% accuracy by naively predicting everything as of class 0, i.e. ignoring class 1 (which, usually, happens to be the class of interest, representing e.g. faults, patients etc).

Nothing of the above is applicable in your case.

Having said that, breaking your dataset into smaller ones depending on the value of your `life_form` feature is not an invalid approach, generally speaking (but not due to class imbalance, non-existing here). The safest way to decide if you should do it, is good old trial-and-error: try it, and try also with your whole dataset. In principle, there is no reason why typical ML algorithms cannot handle such imbalances in the features.